# REDSHIFT : SIZE below 65K BUT "error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit code: 8001"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, listagg

Any chance there may be a bug on Redhisft listagg DISTINCT function?

When I try this

```
select 
case when   partition_field IS NOT NULL  THEN regexp_count(
          listaggdistinct(trim(counted_field), ',')  over (partition by partition_field ), 
        ','
        ) + 1 END AS counted_distinct
from 
TABLE
```

I get the Message ***error:  Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit   code:      8001***

But
I am concatenating on a varchar field whose max length is 18
validated by this query

```
select max(length(counted_field)) from TABLE
```

And If I run the following I get 10 ...

```
select max(COUNTER) from 
    (SELECT  case when   partition_field IS NOT NULL THEN
         count(  counted_field) over (partition by partition_field )
       END as COUNTER
        from TABLE
       )x
```

So 10*18 ... is so much smaller than 65K!!!

What Am I doing wrong?

PLEASE NOTE THAT I HAVE EXCTLY THE SAME RESULTS WITH THIS CODE
THAT IS 100% aligned with Redshift documentation

```
select 
case when   partition_field IS NOT NULL  THEN regexp_count(
          listagg( distinct counted_field, ',')  within group (order by counted_field) over (partition by partition_field ), 
        ','
        ) + 1 END AS counted_distinct
from 
TABLE
```

In this code the `within group (order by contact_id)`  is there just because otherwise Redshift returns a WINDOW error

Comment: Perhaps it is defined as a `char()` rather than a `varchar()` and it gets padded with spaces.

Comment: I just tried explicit casting of the counted_field to varchar(18) ... no improvement
Plus I did several test with the RIGHT function and it fails starting from 5 with  RIGHT(counted_field,5)
I then checked for special characters 
```
select * from(
select counted_field,REGEXP_COUNT(counted_field , '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}$') as test from TABLE
)
where test!=1 ... got nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that partition_field can be null and  to avoid calculation for partition_field NULL the code has to be the following:

```
select 
case  regexp_count(
          listaggdistinct ( 
              CASE WHEN   partition_field IS NOT NULL  
              THEN counted_field END , ','
                         )  over (partition by partition_field ), 
        ','
        ) + 1 END AS counted_distinct
from 
TABLE
```